# Visual Studio 2015 C++ solution can't see svn exe in system PATH

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2015, path

Our team has two separate Visual Studio 2015 C++ projects, which are very similar in terms of project layout, Pre-Build Events etc.

In the Pre-Build Events of the startup project in each solution, an attempt is made to call an exe (svn) in the system PATH.

In solution 1, this works fine, and can execute the svn command.

In solution 2 however, it can't see svn on the PATH.

I've checked and found the following:

- the Pre-Build Event is identical in each solution
- i've compared the .vcxproj files for each Solution and there's nothing apparent
- the full path to the VS Solution that works is longer than the one that doesn't work (so no max file path length issues)
- there are no spaces in the full path names

So my question is, why might one Visual Studio solution be able to see an exe on the PATH, while another with similar layout, *can't*?

Thanks

Comment: The only way to answer this is to forensically examine any and all differences between the two solutions. I get that you've already done that, but you must have missed something, and we won't be able to observe that thing remotely.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Lightness Races in Orbit was correct - I had missed something.

My vcxproj files had different entries for the Project that could see SVN compared to the Project that couldn't see it.

The culprit was the ExecutablePath Property.

Copying the entry from the vcxproj file for the *working* Project to the *non-working* Project allowed the latter to finally find SVN in the PATH.